# How is the renewing process like for an expired Chinese residence permit on expired passport?

Tags: visas, china

I am a student studying in China. My last residence permit expiry date was the same as my passport. Unfortunately my new passport arrived from the embassy 1 day after the expiration date.

Now I have been waiting for almost a month since I submitted my documents to the police station. Is there any one who had the same situation or experience about this process?

Might I face problems for staying over a month in China without a residence permit?

Answer (score 0):

When you renew your residence permit at Gong An, they give you a receipt (that serves as temp ID, since they take your passport), and there should be a date when you should come back and pick up your passport – usually within ten days. If there is no date (I have heard it happens to people, usually from the African continent), you should check with them.